# Procmon gracefully stop

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Following this entry: [exe files being deleted](https://serverfault.com/questions/458120/exe-files-being-deleted)

I was able to setup process monitor to be run from the command line and to log to file.
The issue is that the log file get corrupted upon system restart.

Is there a way to gracefully stop procmon?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Run `procmon /AcceptEula /terminate` to gracefully stop any running procmon trace.